# I cannot hear an audible alert on Google Chat even when sound is enabled

Tags: google-talk

I cannot hear the audible alert on Google Chat even though I have enabled sound in the options. This is so with both Google Chrome and Firefox on Ubuntu Natty. It would be nice to hear a beep of some sort when a typed reply arrives.

Any hints on what further needs to be done is most appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue for a long time and it was due to an add-on configuration. I use Flashblock and Gmail uses Flash to play sounds, so sound playing was getting blocked. It was *not* an Ubuntu specific problem, all I had to do was white list the right URLs:

- `mail.google.com`, for Gmail;
- `www.google.com`, for iGoogle;
- `www.orkut.com`, for Orkut.

I tested this in Ubuntu 12.04 & Firefox 12 (reference [link](http://support.google.com/chat/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=35878)).

Answer (score 2):

Did you try out with Google Chat setting?
[image]

This might help you. If it's not working then your Flash player might be having problems... Try to do a reinstall and it will most probably help you...

I personally use Pidgin which I think is better than using the Google Chat that's inbuilt to Gmail. So if nothing else seem to work better try out an IRC alternative...

Hope this helps ^^

Comment: I do not have the "Sounds on" and "Sounds off" options you have shown above. Instead I have under Google Chat options "Enable Sound" with "Yes" and "No" as tick options. Could it be that I need to update something on my Google account?

Comment: I am using the new Gmail interface well try changing your theme at the settings to Dense

Answer (score 2):

Do you have flash installed? (try to watch a video on youtube if you don't know, if you can see the videos you have flash installed)

Gmail chat uses flash just to play sounds.

Comment: Yes, I can watch videos.